# How can I set my ComboBox to allow the user to type in the first few characters and then automatically select the item by pressing ENTER?

Tags: vb.net, combobox

I have a feeling this is a very simple thing that I'm overlooking.

I have two ComboBoxes that allow users to search for/select the record that they want to view. One is filled with Customer Names and the other is filled with Customer Numbers, so the user can look for a particular record by either selecting the Name or Number.

Each ComboBox is filled by a Data Table returned from a SQL Server database.

Each ComboBox has DropDownStyle set to DropDown, AutoCompleteMode set to SuggestAppend and AutoCompleteSource set to ListItems.

The user can either select by clicking the DropDown arrow and then clicking on the item they was or they can begin by typing and the ComboBox narrows the number of items in the list based on the characters the user is typing.

Using the mouse to click on the item in the list that they want works fine...it fires off a routine to retrieve the selected item from the database.

However, when the user types in the desired selection and presses ENTER, nothing happens. They must click the DropDown arrow and click on the item in order for the program to pull the appropriate record.

How do I get the ComboBox to pull the appropriate record when the user hits enter?

I'm using Visual Basic.

Comment: Show us the code.  We don't know what events you are using.

Comment: If nothing happens automatically when you press a key then obviously you need to handle the appropriate event, detect that key and then do whatever it is you require.  That's what you need to research.

Comment: I'm not sure where the best place to put the code is. In MS Access (VBA), there is an event called "AfterUpdate" which is how our current database application is handled, but Visual Basic (which we're migrating to) doesn't have such an event. Where would be the best place to put the code to handle the selection by ENTER key?

Comment: Right now, I'm using the ComboBox's SelectionChangeCommitted event to pull the record from the SQL Server database. This works when the user clicks the ComboBox drop-down error and then clicks an item in the list, but it does NOT work when the user types in part or all of the number and presses enter or clicks one of the auto-suggestions. Which even do I need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you to JMichael for getting me on the right track with this one. I'm posting my solution here just in case it helps someone who has a similar question in the future:

The code that I added to the ComboBox's SelectionChangeCommitted event needed also to be added to the ComboBox's KeyUp event:

```
Private Sub cboPolicySearch_KeyUp(sended as Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles cboPolicySearch.KeyUp
    If e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter Then
        GetSelectedPolicySearchRecord()
        e.Handled = True
    End If
End Sub     'cboPolicySearch_KeyUp
```

The GetSelectedPolicySearchRecord() sub contained all of the information I needed to call my SQL Stored Procedure to select the data for the record that the user selected in the ComboBox.

Previously, this was only being called from the ComboBox's "SelectionChangeCommitted" event which is executed when the user clicks the drop down and then clicks a policy number from the drop down list.

I needed to add the same call to the GetSelectedPolicySearchRecord in the ComboBox's "KeyUp" event for when the user presses enter.

Answer (score 0):

From the sounds of it, you need three events.

You need to use a timer to know when the user has stopped typing. To do that, you need one event would be when that field they're typing in has it's value change (`<control's name>.TextChanged`). That would start/restart a timer ticking (so that the user has a couple seconds to pause before the next event fires).

The next event would be the `Tick` event for that timer. That event would stop the timer, and then give focus to the right field so that when the user hits ENTER, they're not hitting ENTER in the field they've been typing in. You'll need to write a function to look up the right item in the ComboBox and call that.

Then you'd have a third event, either `KeyPress`, `KeyDown`, or `KeyUp` on the ComboBox itself. I'd lean towards the `KeyUp` to avoid issues if the user holds ENTER for whatever reason. That'd be what selects the item.

As a final FYI, I'm assuming you're using Visual Studio to write your code. If not, you should, and if you are/once you are, you can select the field you want to work with in the drop-down at the top left of the editor and then look at the associated events in the top right drop-down.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I didn't need the Timer, but adding code to the ComboBox's KeyUp event to call my SQL stored procedure when the user presses the ENTER key did work. Thank you again!